# What's the simplest way to request information from (own) other applications

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-contentprovider

The company that I work for has some small android applications running that communicate with their ERP software lately they requested to authenticate users and have sessions for safety reasons

Instead of integrating the autheticate and session code into every app (6) I want to build an Android app that acts like a dashboard. The app will authenticate the user, create a session and show the available apps on the device that the user can access with their user role.

The problem is I need the know which app requires which user role

I don't want to store this information in the dashboard app sinds that will require me to update the dashboard app each time i create or change an app

I was thinking or using an Content provider but that seems to be a lot of work and redundant since it has to be integrated into every app that I have (6)

So my question, is there a way to get data from apps that can easily be implemented. The data isn't big (only one Integer)

thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you considered just using the integrated Android account management?

Comment: No but that probably won't work, the problem is we use QR codes for authentication plus one of our devices (Symbol MC40) doesnt have basic google stuff like playstore and so on

Comment: So you don't actually want a String[] but a byte[][]?

Comment: can you use [android:sharedUserId](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-element.html#uid) ? if so, sharing the simple data would be much [easier](http://localhost/android/guide/topics/security/permissions.html#userid)

Comment: Yes i can use  android:sharedUserId

Comment: *Applications with the same user ID can access each other's data and, if desired, run in the same process.* - use it for easy data sharing